# Huffman, wrong decompressing

Tags: c, algorithm

What am I doing wrong? First I read symbols and frequency. Then build binary Tree. OK. But when I want to write all binary code text into the buffer file, for decompressing, there are shifts.

For example:

compressing buffer file (binary codes):

```
10111110011011111001001000
```

decompressing buffer file(binary codes):

```
10111110101101111110010000100100
```

Of course I write binary codes by 8 bits. But there are artifacts. You can use code and check compressing buffer files with paper - all right. In decompressing buffer files - errors;

parts of code:

```
union CODE {
    unsigned char codeFoFile;
    struct byte {
        unsigned b1 : 1;
        unsigned b2 : 1;
        unsigned b3 : 1;
        unsigned b4 : 1;
        unsigned b5 : 1;
        unsigned b6 : 1;
        unsigned b7 : 1;
        unsigned b8 : 1;
    } byte;
};

//~~~~HOW I WRITE~~~~~//

    fwrite(&countOfLetters, sizeof(int), 1, fileOutput);
    fwrite(&fileBuffSize, sizeof(int), 1, fileOutput);
    fwrite(&tail, sizeof(int), 1, fileOutput);
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfLetters; i++) {
        fwrite(&str[i].ch, sizeof(str[i].ch), 1, fileOutput);
        fwrite(&str[i].freq, sizeof(str[i].freq), 1, fileOutput);
    }
    //---------------
    union CODE code1;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileBuffSize - tail; i++) {
        byteArr[j] = fgetc(fileBuff);
        if (j == 7) {
            code1.byte.b1 = byteArr[0] - '0';
            code1.byte.b2 = byteArr[1] - '0';
            code1.byte.b3 = byteArr[2] - '0';
            code1.byte.b4 = byteArr[3] - '0';
            code1.byte.b5 = byteArr[4] - '0';
            code1.byte.b6 = byteArr[5] - '0';
            code1.byte.b7 = byteArr[6] - '0';
            code1.byte.b8 = byteArr[7] - '0';
            fputc(code1.codeFoFile, fileOutput);
            j = 0;
        }
        j++;
    }
    //work with tail
    j = 0;
    printf("%\n   ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= tail; i++) {
        byteArr[j] = fgetc(fileBuff);
        if (j == tail) {
            code1.byte.b1 = byteArr[0] - '0';
            code1.byte.b2 = byteArr[1] - '0';
            code1.byte.b3 = byteArr[2] - '0';
            code1.byte.b4 = byteArr[3] - '0';
            code1.byte.b5 = byteArr[4] - '0';
            code1.byte.b6 = byteArr[5] - '0';
            code1.byte.b7 = byteArr[6] - '0';
            code1.byte.b8 = byteArr[7] - '0';
            fputc(code1.codeFoFile, fileOutput);
        }
        j++;
    }

    //~~~~HOW I READ~~~~~//

    for (int i = 0; i < fileBuffSize + tail; i++) {
        //charFile = fgetc(fileInput);
        fread(&charFile, sizeof(char), 1, fileInput);
        code1.codeFoFile = charFile;
        //code1.codeFoFile = charFile;
        if (charFile != NULL && charFile != 1) {
            buff[0] = code1.byte.b1 + '0';
            buff[1] = code1.byte.b2 + '0';
            buff[2] = code1.byte.b3 + '0';
            buff[3] = code1.byte.b4 + '0';
            buff[4] = code1.byte.b5 + '0';
            buff[5] = code1.byte.b6 + '0';
            buff[6] = code1.byte.b7 + '0';
            buff[7] = code1.byte.b8 + '0';
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                printf("%c", buff[i]);
            printf("\n");
            fwrite(&buff, sizeof(buff), 1, buffFile);
        }
        charFile = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: You _really should_ post the relevant part of your code _right in the question_.

Comment: Is the data in the file correct? Start there, and then you narrowed down where to look.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i check data in file, in compressed file. 
I used different methods work with file.

Comment: @ForceBru some parts of code added in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems in your code:

- The order of bit fields is implementation defined. You cannot be sure which bit of `codeFoFile` correspond to `byte.b1` etc.  Your code is not portable and may be incorrect for the algorithm you mean to implement.
- `printf("%\n   ");` is incorrect. Did you mean `printf("\n   ");`?
- In the writing loop, your handling of tail is incorrect: you should not do anything if `tail == 0`, initialize all bytes in `byteArr` to `0`, read `tail` bytes into the first `tail` elements and store into the bits after the loop.
- In the reading loop, you should check the return value of `fread` to verify is data was read properly into `charFile`.
- I don't understand why you test `if (charFile != NULL && charFile != 1)` next. `NULL` is a null pointer constant, it may expand to `0`, especially if you compile with a C++ compiler, but in any case, `0` and `1` are perfectly valid binary values that may be produced by the compression algorithm.  Ignoring them is incorrect.
- Commenting your code in Russian does not help casual readers across the globe.

Comment: how i should check return value of fread?

Comment: `fread` returns the number of entries read.  It should return `1` if  a byte was read by `fread(&charFile, sizeof(char), 1, fileInput)`

Comment: You can tell more about the tail, and what to do with him directly at decompressing

Comment: Maybe later, I cannot do this while driving `;-)`

Comment: okey:D 
if not difficult

Comment: i checked how my programm write - he stole 1 bit always !!!

Comment: and always - 1st bit

Comment: now all works! but new problem. text files - compress and decompress - nice. mp3,jpb,bmp - wrong